# Why does simple matrix multiplication occupy so much garbage collector time in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, multiplication

I have two large-ish matrices D (4096 x 40) and W (40 x 2800).

when I use `@time R = D*W` this gives the following stats:

```
38.449856 seconds (1.40 G allocations: 20.932 GiB, 55.88% gc time)
```

The 55.88% gc time was shocking to me. There must be a better way of doing this simple matrix calculation. Any ideas for this Julia novice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide more information on how you generate `D` and `W` (or at least what their types are).

This is what I get:

```
julia> D = rand(4096, 40); W = rand(40, 2800);

julia> @time R = D * W;
  0.081237 seconds (7 allocations: 87.500 MiB, 6.74% gc time)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're measuring compilation as well. If you run any other matrix multiplication before, you'll see a result 10x faster with very little allocation

Comment: Compilation time wouldn't cause a 30 second overhead in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It did not occur to me this was a type issue. In my code the D matrix is `Array{Float64,2}` and W is `Array{Real,2}`.

Conversion from real to float yields the following:

```
  0.024569 seconds (6 allocations: 87.500 MiB, 36.84% gc time)
```

Much improved!

Comment: No, this was definitely not a type issue. This was something else, maybe you measured the compilation time and allocations in your first attempt. Multiplying floats with reals should be fine...

Comment: Although 40 seconds is quite rough ; ) could you reproduce it?

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes more sense. You were hitting 2 problems. 1st dispatch, 2nd, generic multiplication rather than BLAS multiplication